# Eigenvalues of a block Hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices, hermitian-matrices

Suppose I have a matrix like the following

$$A= \begin{pmatrix}
B & y \\
y^{*} & a \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $B$ is a Hermitian matrix. How can I prove that

\begin{equation}
\lambda_{1}(A)\leq \lambda_{1}(B)\leq \lambda_{2}(A)\leq \dots \leq \lambda_{n}(A)\leq 
\lambda_{n}(B)\leq \lambda_{n+1}(A)
\end{equation}

I know that I should somehow use Weyl inequality. But I don't know how.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Cauchy interlacing theorem perhaps?

Comment: @johanatan This is an instance of the result known as the [Cauchy interlacing theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem). It is easiest to prove as a consequence of the min-max theorem, AKA the Courant-Fischer theorem.